# Dynamic Linking to visa32.dll causes crash

Tags: c++

I am trying to communicate with an oscilloscope over USB with NI-VISA 5.1.1. My 32-bit application is written in the Qt framework using C++ and the MinGW compiler (standard Qt 4.7 SDK).

My application has no problems communicating with the device when I statically link to visa32.lib. My dynamically linked code also runs fine on a Windows 7 64-bit platform, but crashes on two different computers running on Windows XP SP3 (32 bit). I have traced the line of code that causes the crash (it is the first call to viWrite).

The issue seems to be related to setup of global variables in the DLL itself. This might explain why it works in Windows 7 since in that case the 32-bit DLL file is only a stub which calls a 64-bit VISA DLL file.

This is how I dynamically link to the exported functions:

```
typedef long (*tviRead)(ViSession, ViPBuf, ViUInt32, ViPUInt32);
typedef long (*tviWrite)(ViSession, ViBuf, ViUInt32, ViPUInt32);

QLibrary visa32("visa32");   // Qt wrapper for LoadLibrary
if (!visa32.load()) throw "Unable to load visa32.dll";
pviWrite = (tviWrite) visa32.resolve("viWrite");
pviRead = (tviRead) visa32.resolve("viRead");
```

If I call the following (where the `vi` prefixed function are statically linked and pvi ones are runtime linked),

```
status = viOpenDefaultRM(&rm);
status = viFindRsrc(rm, query, &list, &itemCnt, desc);
status = viOpen(rm, desc, VI_NULL, VI_NULL, &vi);
status = pviWrite(vi, (ViByte*) idn, 5, &retCnt);       // Crash right here
status = pviRead(vi, (ViByte*) id, sizeof(id), &retCnt);
```

everything works perfectly. However changing any of the three setup function to runtime linked causes a segmentation fault when calling pviWrite. There aren't AFAIK any other functions exported by the DLL to "setup global variables", in fact I can't see DllMain exported using the [Dependency Walker](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_Walker) tool. Has anyone ever runtime linked to visa32.dll successfully? I can't find any examples on the Internet.

Comment: Did `viWrite` fail to resolve by any chance?  *ie* is `pviWrite` NULL?

Comment: Sorry I left out all the error checking code for clarity. The above does work, it's when I change viOpen to pviOpen that it breaks.

Comment: Sorry I keep asking you probing questions...  Do you use any STL containers in your `ViSession`?  eg `std::string`, `std::vector` etc?  That can lead to DLL dramas.

Comment: No prob... ViSession actually typedefs to unsigned long (it's a handle), the others are ViPBuf & ViBif: unsigned char*, ViUInt32: unsigned long and ViPUInt32: unsigned long*

Comment: I have the same issue. I run the code on two different computers with two different primary visa installations and the code fails on one of them.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you have the following problem:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684179(v=vs.85).aspx

Scroll down to the remarks section, and look for "Visual C++": if the DLL contains _declspec-style thread local storage you can only load it dynamically in Vista or later.

I'm trying to achieve the same thing but apparently, for XP, we are simply out of luck...